# FTP Remote site showing empty directory

Tags: ftp

Trying to ftp to my website using Filezilla and Cyberduck both are showing empty directories under root. What could I be doing wrong? There are many files in file manger on Cpanel.

Comment: We cannot say. You have to add much more details for us to be able to understand your situation. Keep in mind that we cannot look over your shoulder...

Comment: You should figure out which folder in the filesystem is being displayed when you use ftp vs which folder cpanel shows you. They seem to be different.

Comment: it shows the / folder and an folder named incoming, it also shows a file named ftpquota. The file manager has dozens of folders and files

Comment: ok what type of information would you need, I can provide it

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @FransB are your logging in using master/root login , or the one created using cpanel "FTP accounts" page

Comment: ftp accounts page

Comment: @Raja Gopal Thanks man, your answer led me straight to the problem, I liged in from the root master account and my files showed up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that I logged in from ftp account I had created in C panel and not the master root account. Now it works.